# Can php warnings cause an Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, 500-internal-error, internal-server-error

A client's WordPress site crashes for a few minutes once to twice a day. When I review the error log, there are a number of PHP warnings (e.g. undefined variable, undefined array key, etc.) but no fatal PHP errors. From the WP error log, the errors first arose on August 10th, which has me believe it may be a result of upgrading to WP6... I plan to resolve each issue, but am curious if these PHP warnings would be enough to crash the site? Or is there anything else that could be causing these intermittent crashes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Warnings should not crash a site, but I guess it depends on what you mean by crash? If your error log density has increased, I'd guess it was more likely due to a PHP update than a WP update.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post to include the error message. I also thought it may have been a PHP update, but I switched from PHP 7.x.x to PHP 8.x.x back in May, and the errors started showing in August.

Comment: If there are no fatal errors in WordPress's logs (I assume you're using `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to see them), the next place to check is probably the server's apache|nginx logs, if you can access them.